# BUILD SUCCESS even after failures in test

Tags: java, maven, automation, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

I have added cucumber report plugin in pom.xml as follows:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
            <version>${maven.cucumber.reporting.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>execution</id>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <projectName>cucumber-jvm-example</projectName>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/cucumber-html-reports</outputDirectory>
                        <cucumberOutput>${project.build.directory}/cucumber.json</cucumberOutput>
                        <parallelTesting>false</parallelTesting>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

which will generate reports only if there is no failure, but to generate report even after failure I had to add:

```
<testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
```

in the maven surefire plugin, this is generation report even after failure in test but problem is BUILD SUCCESS message generated and it should be BUILD FAILURE.
any idea?

Comment: So you're telling it to ignore test failures, and then you're surprised that it ignores test failures? The problem you need to solve is how to generate the report after failure - clearly ignoring test failures is not the correct way for that.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt I am new to automation so I used that sollution, which I should not use it but without that its not generating report

Comment: Try opening an [issue](https://github.com/damianszczepanik/maven-cucumber-reporting/issues).